# Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected using json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using `JSON` values like below

```
$.each(UMSGroupDetails, function (index, element) {
            if (element.GroupName == UserGrouop.CT) {
                umsGroupNameTo = element.GroupName;
                umsGroupIdTo = element.GroupID;
            }
        });
```

and its json data like this

```
[{"GroupName":"CMM","GroupID":625},{"GroupName":"Construction_Eng","GroupID":626},{"GroupName":"DY. CTO","GroupID":624},{"GroupName":"Fiber Engineer","GroupID":622},{"GroupName":"Fiber Lead","GroupID":623}]
```

but getting error as

> Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

Please suggest what is wrong here

**MORE INFO**

```
 var LoginUserName = "Nadeem5.khan";
    var UMSGroupDetailsObj = function () { return [{"GroupName":"CMM","GroupID":625},{"GroupName":"Construction_Eng","GroupID":626},{"GroupName":"DY. CTO","GroupID":624},{"GroupName":"Fiber Engineer","GroupID":622},{"GroupName":"Fiber Lead","GroupID":623}]; }
    var UMSGroupDetails = JSON.stringify(UMSGroupDetailsObj());

    var CurrentGroupName = "Fiber Engineer";
    var CurrentGroupID = "622";
    var UMSLocationDetailsObj = function () { return [{"LocationName":"Kalyan","LocationID":"INMUKLYN01"}]; }
    var UMSLocationDetails = JSON.stringify(UMSLocationDetailsObj())
```

Comment: `UserGrouop.CT` is this spelled correctly?

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with json. That's an array containing objects.

Comment: Are these variables defined previously umsGroupNameTo, umsGroupIdTo with var. Other than that and UserGrouop.CT as mentioned above you're fine

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: yes its like that only. so how should I access it ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: see my updated question. I want to compare and access it

Comment: There's your problem, you're iterating over `UMSGroupDetails` which is a string, not an array.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: pls help how to access it. I m not sure

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: how should I iterate it then ??

Comment: Don't `stringify` it

Answer (score 0):

Dont do JSON.stringify(UMSGroupDetailsObj()); since you have already json format

```
 var LoginUserName = "Nadeem5.khan";
    var UMSGroupDetailsObj = function () { return [{"GroupName":"CMM","GroupID":625},{"GroupName":"Construction_Eng","GroupID":626},{"GroupName":"DY. CTO","GroupID":624},{"GroupName":"Fiber Engineer","GroupID":622},{"GroupName":"Fiber Lead","GroupID":623}]; }
    var UMSGroupDetails = UMSGroupDetailsObj;

    var CurrentGroupName = "Fiber Engineer";
    var CurrentGroupID = "622";
    var UMSLocationDetailsObj = function () { return [{"LocationName":"Kalyan","LocationID":"INMUKLYN01"}]; }
    var UMSLocationDetails = JSON.stringify(UMSLocationDetailsObj())
```

Also please check json format is correct ?